# How do I make a SQL Query only fire when a user "expands" a gridviewrow?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, twitter-bootstrap

At the moment, I have a GridView that pulls from a SQL data source.  Every row has a summary in it, and when a user clicks expand on the row, they get a DetailsView with the details of that particular item in it.

I'm looking for a way to make it so DetailsView only binds to the DataSource when the row is expanded.  At the moment it happens on RowDataBound, which results in heaps of queries going back and forth between the SQL server and the ASP NET server.

I'd also like to use Bootstrap to expand and collapse these rows, so it looks good when it expands or collapses.

Any help would be very much appreciated :) I've really tried to find some resources that would assist me in the above, but I've come up bumpkis.  The closest I've gotten is an AJAX CollapsiblePanel, but it loads everything at Page_Load anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You are battling two different areas here, and this comment is the one that makes it more complicated:

> I'd also like to use Bootstrap to expand and collapse these rows, so it looks good when it expands or collapses.<

What I did was use BS panels and a repeater and with this approach, you can still databind details on a click event but you need some hidden controls inside your item templates for your DetailsView to bind the correct data.  When you "loop" through your summary data, you'll need to provide an accurate link to BS expanding child - presumably an identifier and then another hidden control with the same.  Run the link on the server so you can have a click event and assign the datasource and databind there.

Depending on how long it take your data to load, you might consider avoiding the databind on every click.  If you are using BS to make it elegant, it seems counterproductive to add a postback - at least on the user experience/elegance side.  I understand the want to avoid so many data calls though.

Hopefully this will get you started:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeatCont" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
<HeaderTemplate>
    <div class="panel-inner">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accCont"> // parent
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="panel panel-dark-gray">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h5 class="panel-title">
                <a class="panel-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accCont" href='<%# "#" + Eval("MATCHID1") %>'>  // add a postback here with linkbutton or javascript postback force - easier just do bind your child data because you'll have two different trying to happen - postback and data-toggle
                    <div>
                       //stuff on the panel
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <br />
                    </div>
                </a>
            </h5>
        </div>           

        <div id='<%# Eval("MATCHID1") %>' class="panel-body collapse">
           //Hidden label with your MATCH ID 1 again - this is where you will tell your DetailsView to look for parameter

           //put your details view here

        </div>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
    </div>
 </div>
</FooterTemplate>
```

Comment: Okay, if I didn't want to run it in that way, so the data was filled out on the first page load, how would I do that instead?